# Missing server domain template in MapProxy

Tags: mapproxy

I need to pass the `{s}` template in my TMS source but after reading this:

https://mapproxy.org/docs/latest/sources.html#url

I think it is not possible.

Is it correct I can't do this in MapProxy?:

```
https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png
Subdomains: mt1, mt2, mt3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is currently not possible in Mapproxy - https://github.com/mapproxy/mapproxy/issues/206.

The referenced issue's thread mentions that the need for subdomains is typically used as a workaround for browser limitations ([Max parallel HTTP connections in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser)), but i am not sure why this is a good reason for not supporting the feature when you want to be able to server common browsers as fast as possible...

A possible solution will be to implement the same behavior by using HTTP2 ([HTTP2 VS HTTP1](https://cheapsslsecurity.com/p/http2-vs-http1/)), which has this as a default ([HTTP2 multiplexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517829/what-does-multiplexing-mean-in-http-2)).